# Mongodb Pymongo , import json file

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Mongod and pymongo is running correctly. Want to import a jsonfile now.

```
import pymongo

mongoimport --db test --collection dots --file c:\created.json
```

It just throws me a syntax error in sublimetext with no further explanation, Anyone sees what it is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with windows, but either it is a problem with 'c:\' or your file is corrupted. Does it work for the files in your cwd?

Answer (score 3):

`mongoimport` is a command line utility and is independent of `pymongo`, which is the MongoDB driver for Python. So just launch your `cmd` and run there:

`mongoimport --db test --collection dots --file c:\created.json`